# Double precision in parentheses in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision

Working with a double, I can set

```
double x = 216/22            //Output's 9.818181...
```

However, when I try:

```
double x = (216/22)          //Outputs 9.00000...
double x = ((double)216/22)  //Outputs 9.0000...
double x = (216/(double)22)  //Outputs 9.818181...
```

Why does (216/22) return 9 and not 9.8181...?

Comment: A better question is why don't you get 9 when there are no parentheses.

Comment: This: `double x = ((double)216/22)  //Outputs 9.0000...` is almost certainly wrong (it should yield 9.8181...). I'd guess you really tried something like: `double x = (double)(216/22);` instead (that really should produce 9.000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does (216/22) return 9 and not 9.8181...?

Because both 216 and 22 are `int` - and the result is an int.

`(216.0/22)` would return double as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    double w = 216/22;
    double x = (216/22);
    double y = ((double)216/22);
    double z = (216/(double)22);

    printf("w %lf\n",w);
    printf("x %lf\n",x);
    printf("y %lf\n",y);
    printf("z %lf\n",z);
    return(0);
}
```

output exactly as expected

```
w 9.000000
x 9.000000
y 9.818182
z 9.818182
```

Two integer divisions converted to double, then two double divisions.  If you didnt get that then something is wrong with your compiler or your code or pilot error handling the experiment.  Then after you solve your compiler/code issue then consult C tutorial documentation on typecasting.  You told the compiler to do an integer division, which means there is no fractional remainder, then you converted that integer 9 to a double 9.0.  For the other two you asked the compiler to convert the integers to double first then do a double divide, which means you get to keep the fractional remainder.

then if you do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

union
{
    unsigned int ui[2];
    double d;
} myun;

int main ( void )
{
    double w = 216/22;
    double x = (216/22);
    double y = ((double)216/22);
    double z = (216/(double)22);
    unsigned int r = (1/10)*10;
    unsigned int s = ((double)1/10)*10;
    unsigned int t = (1/10.0)*10;

    printf("w %lf\n",w);
    printf("x %lf\n",x);
    printf("y %lf\n",y);
    printf("z %lf\n",z);
    printf("r %u\n",r);
    printf("s %u\n",s);
    printf("t %u\n",t);
    return(0);
}
```

you get

```
w 9.000000
x 9.000000
y 9.818182
z 9.818182
r 0
s 1
t 1
```

exactly as expected.

this doesnt change the output for this test

```
unsigned int t = (1/10.0F)*10;
```

but it is doing something different than without the F in there.

Answer (score 1):

`double x = (216/22)`
Is interpreted as two integers, then the result is casted to a double. If you want to do this without casting, and keep precision, do:

`double x = (216.0/22.0) // outputs 9.818181...`

Answer (score 0):

By the line:
`double x = (216/22) //Outputs 9.00000...`, you are performing an integer division to specify both values as double:
`double x = 216.0/22.0`  or `double x = (double)216/(double)22`

If either of the values were to have been of type `double` or casted to it then the resultant would be of type `double`.